# One Side Page Vertical Scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to make one side of a page scroll. An example would be something like https://shop.luxonis.com/. The solution I came up with was styling the right column as such

```
.right-column {
   overflow-y: scroll;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

But this makes the page have two scroll wheels. Any ideas? I know the site I gave uses position sticky, but I'm not sure what else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) for the left panel

Here is [the playground](https://jsfiddle.net/9vs5tjem/)

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: orange;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

.left-panel {
  position: sticky; /* Set the element to become sticky  */
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0; /* Set the sticky positon top */
}

.right-panel {
  height: 1000rem;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.footer {
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="header">

</div>
<div class="flexbox">
<div class="left-panel">
     Content
  </div>
  <div class="right-panel">
     Scrolling content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two div containers, left and right one,
the left one is gonna have only one element and the right one gonna have multiple elements.